# PivotTable: Dealing with large CommandText due to temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, pivot, temp-tables

I have the following `CommandText` for a pivot table's connection:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(KonPos integer, KonStk integer);
INSERT INTO #temptable (KonPos, KonStk) Values
(1,1),(2,1),(3,1);

SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM
  #temptable a LEFT JOIN dbTable b ON a.KonPos = b.Position

DROP TABLE #temptable;
```

I am using VBA to create the inserted rows and the temp table is a bit more complex than this but needless to say, the string gets too big in size.

If anyone wonders how I create the query:

```
sQuery = sQuery & "INSERT INTO #temptable (KonPos, KonStk) Values" & Chr(10)
sQuery = sQuery & Join(TableRows, ",") & ";"
```

This command replaces the CommandText:
`wbCn.CommandText = ReplaceQueryTempTalbe(sQuery, wbCn.CommandText)`

It does nothing but replace the placeholder within the query with the table rows.

Anyone with a solution that would work? I am open to various ideas.

Edit:

```
DBMS:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012                     11.0.2100.60
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, added it, it's `MSSQL 2012`

Answer (score 0):

I now found a way of doing it, it's not 100% fool proof because it isn't always stable (e.g. it never works the first time I open the file but everytime afterwards).

The way of doing it for me:
Create a global temp table in the database which eliminates the restriction in the connection command text.

For that I changed the command text for the pivot table:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(KonPos integer, KonStk integer);

DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000);
INSERT INTO #temptable (KonPos, KonStk)    
SELECT * FROM ##GlobalTempTable;
SET @sqlCommand = 'DROP TABLE ##GlobalTempTable';

SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM
  #temptable a LEFT JOIN dbTable b ON a.KonPos = b.Position

DROP TABLE #temptable;
EXEC (@sqlCommand);
```

The query to insert the rows is still done the same way but just for the global temp table and executed in VBA.

```
Private Sub GlobalTempTableErstellen(GlobalTempTableName As String)
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim sQuery As String

cn.Open strConnection

sQuery = "SET NOCOUNT ON" & _
        " CREATE TABLE " & GlobalTempTableName & _
        " (KonPos integer, KonStk integer); " & _
        CreateTempTable(GlobalTempTableName)

cn.Execute sQuery
cn.Close
End Sub
```

So the way it is done now:

1. Create the global temp table via VBA.
2. Generate the command text code
   also in VBA.
3. Refresh the database connection which includes dropping
   the global temp table.